# Managing old elements by timestamp in Redis sorted set

Tags: php, redis

You have a sorted set A in redis, every now and then you add new elements to it, they get sorted by rank e.g. You also have a sorted set B.

Is there a way to check if there are elements in set A that have been there for more then say 20 seconds, and move them to sorted set B

because this checking operation is done very frequently, and list can be very big, iterating through every element in set is a not a good solution. Need fastest one.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Here is what I was trying to do:
Basically the idea was, imagine you have some kind of game server that matches opponents when they put a fight request. The current design was that every request get's to the set, and the rank/score is the player rank. so that way every 2 players that are near each other in the list are perfect matches. every 5 seconds or so a script get's called that pulls 50 rows from top of set, and matches them 2 by 2 (and removes them). This was working fine, and I think that was a very fast working solution. But then the idea of creating a Bot (AI) players came. so that when player is waiting too long in que, he get's matched with a bot (AI) player. And I cannot figure out a way to see "who is waiting too long" Basically maybe the entire idea was wrong.. so any better ideas are welcome :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can use an auxiliary ordered set in which you could store your elements with their timestamps as the scores.

Comment: not sure if I can use timestamp as score, as the score used for something else. I updated the post with more info. Thanks!

Comment: I am proposing to create another ordered set, in addition to the existing ones, and use timestamps as scores.

Comment: If I use timestamps as scores, I will not be able to use "user ratings" as scores, so the matching will not work correctly.

Comment: again, you can have three ordered sets: A and B as you have in the original question, and C where you store the same items as in A but with timestamps as scores.

Comment: thanks! sounds like a plan!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the score in your sorted set is a unix timestamp, you can use [zrange](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) to grab the oldest NN items from set A. You can then do your checks, add qualifying entries to set B, then remove them from set A.

If your scoring in set A is not based on timestamp, then you will have to iterate over your set A entirely, or rethink your design. Redis keys do not have an inherent available timestamp of when they are added (which holds doubly true for items in a key such as a sorted set), so it has to be something you specifically create and track. Perhaps if you share more about what you are doing and why we can help with more detail.

Edit:
based on the additions to your questions, I would recommend trying a solution similar to what @akonsu is proposing.

Specifically:
Sorted-Set-A: players by rank just as they are now.

Sorted-Set-B:
uses timestamp as the time the person went into the queue, stores their userid. In other words, when you zadd to SetA with their rank & ID, you zadd to SetB with the timestamp and ID.

When you match players you remove them from both sets. If you pull your set of users to match from SetB using a zrange command to grab the X oldest entries, you will have the time they queued up, in order of their entry (like a FIFO). You then use a zrange command on SetA with their rank +/- whatever rank range you need. If you get a match you proceed with the match by removing them from both sets and moving on.

If there is no suitable opponent in SetA and their timestamp is old enough you match with an AI, then remove them from both sets and move on.

Essentially it is an index queue of users->timestamp. Doing it this way mean shorter queue times for all users as you are now matching them in order of queue length. You still use SetA for matching based on players' rank, but now you are indexing and prioritizing based on time.

The specific implementation may be a bit more interesting than this, but as an overall stratagem I think this fits what you need.